# Swift - Strings: Sequences or not?

Tags: swift, string, sequence

I just want to sort this out once and for all:

In Swift. Can the string data type be treated as a sequence in the same way as, for example arrays and tuples?

```
func printAnySequence<T: SequenceType>(anything: T) {
    for element in anything {
        print("\(element),")
    }
}

printAnySequence("A random string")
```

The code above generates a compiler error with the message: "Cannot invoke printAnySequence" with an argument list of type string.

```
let randomString: String = "A random string"

for char in randomString {
    print(char)
}
```

Whereas the code above generate a compiler error with the message: "Type 'String' does not conform to the protocol 'SequenceType'"

However the documentation for Swift explicitly says that strings are fixed sequences of characters.

[image]

Where is my error?

Thanks
Max Xie

Comment: The answer is "no". If you want a sequence of characters, use `string.characters`. The word sequence in the documentation describes the nature of strings, it doesn't say anything about type `SequenceType`. Also, a string literal is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

No, `String` does not implement `SequenceType`. The documentation calls a string literal a "fixed sequence of textual characters", but this doesn't have anything to do with the `SequenceType` protocol. `String.characters`, however, has type `String.CharacterView` which *does* implement `SequenceType` (it even implements `BidirectionalCollectionType`).

If you really wanted to, you could let `String` conform to `BidirectionalCollectionType` (and `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`) very easily:

```
extension String: BidirectionalCollectionType, RangeReplaceableCollectionType {
    // String already implements the necessary methods
    // and properties, so we can leave this empty
}
```

However, this is not recommended. The core Swift team left out these conformances for a reason: methods in protocol extensions on `SequenceType`, `CollectionType` and other protocols might make assumptions about the sequence/collection that might not hold for `String`, due to the nature of Swift strings.